# Zend Session save_path NOT not working

Tags: zend-framework, session, authentication, directory

I hope you guys can help me ,

In my Zend application I'm setting the Zend_Auth session files to be saved in a specific folder because I am using a shared hosting. Apparently I have got everything right but the problem is that the sessions are not being stored in the folder I want.

In the application.ini I have:

```
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session/"
resources.session.use_only_cookies = true
```

In the bootstrap I have:

```
protected function _initSessions() 
{
    $this->bootstrap('session');
}
```

The authentication method

```
$adapter = $this->getAuthAdapter();
$adapter->setIdentity($userName)->setCredential($hPassword);

$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$result  = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
$user = $this->_userModel->getUserAuthData($userName);
$auth->getStorage()->write($user);
```

The application authenticates fine but the session files are still being saved in de /tmp folder instead of APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session/".

The folder /data/session has chmod 777.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Does it work if you comment out your bootstrap _initSessions method?

Comment: Hi Tim, thks for helping. The login still works and the session file is still being stored in the /temp folder, so nothing changed.

Comment: Do any of your other bootstrap methods use session related functionality?

Comment: No, the other methods are viewSettings, Routes and moduleAutoloader and no session functionality is used.

Comment: could you try  ini_set('session.save_path', $path) maybe you are not allowed to change the value?

Comment: It sets without problem AmeRie.

Comment: hum you could try to use an fullpath .. not sure if there is a problem with "APPLICATION_PATH" and ini_set

Comment: I found it! After Tim asked if there was any other session related functionality happening in the bootstrap I decided to check what was happening before bootstrap and found this line "Zend_Session::start();" in the public/index.php before bootstrap-run(). I Removed it and it worked. The problem: Zend_Session::start() was creating the session file without applying any configuration that was set in the application.ini (because this occurs during bootstrap).
Tim and ArneRie thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Tim Fountain asked (in the question's comments) if there was any other session related functionality happening in the bootstrap I decided to check what was happening before bootstrap and found this line in the public/index.php file.

```
Zend_Session::start();
```

It was just before $application->bootstrap()->run(). I Removed it and it worked.

The problem: Zend_Session::start() was creating the session file without applying any configuration that was being set in the application.ini (because this runs during the bootstrap process).